# Selecting an value and forming an array object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, antd

I want to create data from available data to form an array of objects,

Like example - I have data of array object like this

```
[
    {
        _id: "some id",
        name: "Example",
        value: "value,
    },
    {
        _id: "some id",
        name: "Example",
        value: "value,
    }
    {
        _id: "some id",
        name: "Example",
        value: "value,
    }
]
```

Now I am collecting data and want to form an array of the object from the above data:

```
[
    {
        value_id:"some id"
    },
    {
        value_id:"some id"
    },
    {
        value_id:"some id"
    }
]
```

like above as an output:
here's a link for that I am trying to render table as selected table values,
Using ant design

https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-field-rw3m2?file=/index.js

Can someone help me with this?

Edit- At codesandbox, I want the same, when I check the item then it be as an above expected output. Like when I select Filter 0 and Filter 1 then the id of both would be there

```
 [
        {
            value_id:"some id"
        },
        {
            value_id:"some id"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: you can use `const values = orginalArray.map(x => { value_id: x._id });`

Comment: @DTul you have a small syntax error :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `Array.prototype.map`.

```js
var arr = [
    {
        _id: "some id",
        name: "Example",
        value: "value"
    },
    {
        _id: "some id",
        name: "Example",
        value: "value"
    },
    {
        _id: "some id",
        name: "Example",
        value: "value"
    }
];

var newArr = arr.map(o => ({value_id : o._id}));

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Can you help on code sandbox? I am trying to get it when it is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Use the map function of the Array in order to get the new array.

```
let newArray = data.map(item => {
  if(selectedRowKeys.includes(item.key))
    return { value_id: item._id };
  else return null;
});

newArray = newArray.filter(item => item !== null);

console.log(newArray);
```

sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-pasteur-icxpb?file=/index.js

Comment: On selecting table value, I want result like the way`[
    {
        value_id:"some id"
    },
    {
        value_id:"some id"
    },
    {
        value_id:"some id"
    }
]` with selected id as value_id

Comment: done! check the sandbox in the onSelectChange function

Comment: I don't see any update there, can you check and reshare? Also check the updated question. I want that expected output in selected key console.

Comment: sure check this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-pasteur-icxpb?file=/index.js
when select a row a log will appear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219417/discussion-between-emiacc-and-zeus-carl).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Array#map` function. Important note: it doesn't change the original array, you have to save the result in a new variable:

```js
const originalArray = [
    {
        _id: "some id",
        name: "Example",
        value: "value",
    },
    {
        _id: "some id",
        name: "Example",
        value: "value",
    },
    {
        _id: "some id",
        name: "Example",
        value: "value",
    }
];

const idArray = originalArray.map(item => ({ value_id: item._id }));

console.log(idArray);
console.log(originalArray); // Unchanged
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't tell your requirements but looking at your sandbox, i understood you want to map your selected rows :

```
[0, 5, 10]
```

To :

```
[
    {
        value_id: "some id"
    },
    {
        value_id:"some id"
    },
    {
        value_id:"some id"
    }
]
```

which the ids are comming from the data. so you can use:

```
  onSelectChange = (selectedRowKeys) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedRowKeys: selectedRowKeys,
      selectedRowKeysFormatted: selectedRowKeys.map((id) => ({
        value_id: data[id]._id
      }))
    });
  })
```

Note that ant design needs a state for selecting the rows which looks like:

```
[0, 5, 10]
```

so you should create another state variable to store the format you need, not changing the state that antd is using for.

[Code On Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-newton-z3p15?file=/index.js)